ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.STN'
I installed utils module (all possible versions from 0.1 to 1.0.2) with for example:
pip install utils==1.0.2

and so on, in Python 3.7.7 (interpreter is venv). But every time, I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.STN'

What do I do? Thank you.

Where did you get the code you are seeing this line? utils.STN does not seem to be from that pypi package. utils could also be a local collection of functions that whoever wrote the script you are trying to run had lying around

Ooh I see now.. I completely overlooked that the writer of the code posted utils functions as well.. Thank you so much!
